# Skip non existing sessions for a form if they do not apply

Tags: forms, coldfusion, form-submit

What I have is a form website page that will automatically fill out the required form with the information entered from the form website page. What I am trying to figure out is if `#session.checkout.info.firstname_2#` does not exist how do you skip it and not make the form worry about it?

So there are two fields one for owner and the other for co-owner, if there is only one owner the page is not opening the form because its looking for something to be entered as `firstname_2` but if both owner and co-owner are entered it works fine because all fields are then entered. Does anyone know how I can make it only worry about the fields that have been submitted from the first form and ignore the sessions that have not yet been entered?

```
<cfif len(#session.checkout.info.firstname_2#)>
    <cfpdfformparam 
      name="co-owner name" 
      value="#session.checkout.info.firstname_2# #session.checkout.info.middlename_2# #session.checkout.info.lastname_2#">
</cfif>
```

Comment: Vicki, can you just use cfparam? ...As in `<cfparam name="session.checkout.info.firstname_2" value=""/>` then it will be sure to exist. Does it hurt anything to populate it with an empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isDefined` to check that the variable does not exist.

```
<cfif isDefined("session.checkout.info.firstname_2")>
  <cfpdfformparam 
    name="co-owner name" 
    value="#session.checkout.info.firstname_2# #session.checkout.info.middlename_2# #session.checkout.info.lastname_2#">
</cfif>
```

If you also need to check length you can combine the above if with what you've written.

Generally it's a better practice to use `structKeyExists()` but when there are multiple item that may not exist it can be cumbersome, i.e. `structKeyExists(session, 'checkout') && structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info') && structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'firstname_2')`